# Receive fetch() binary stream in ASP.Net Core backend?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-core, file-upload, asp.net-core-webapi

In my frontend I am uploading a file to my backend with this JavaScript code:

```
const file = document.getElementById('file');

const response = await fetch("https://localhost:5333/upload", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: file
});

console.log(`upload response status code: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
const json = await response.json();

console.log(`response json: ${JSON.stringify(json) }`);
```

(I do not want to use `FormData`, as I am only uploading one file)

My controller looks like this:

```
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class UploadController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    public UploadResponse Upload() // <----- which parameter type do I need here?
    {
        return new UploadResponse
        {
            SomeProperty = "some value"
        };
    }
}
```

Which parameter type do I need for my backend `Upload()` method to receive the file from the frontend as a stream?

Answer (score 0):

Usually it's the IFormFile class you would use:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return BadRequest("No file provided");
    }

    //to do

    return Ok(new UploadResponse
    {
        SomeProperty = "some value"
    });
}
```